# SQLITE is extreme slow with ORDER BY

Tags: database, performance, sqlite, sorting

I have a simple query like

```
SELECT * FROM "mytable" where col1="foo"
```

which resolves in around 0.5 seconds (approx. 100 results of approx 100'000 rows of a 700 MB database file)

However, as soon as I add `ORDER BY` it takes 120 seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM "mytable" where col1="foo" ORDER BY col2
```

Even when I limit the result like so

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM "mytable" where col1="foo" LIMIT 1) ORDER BY col2
```

it takes 120 seconds although there's literally nothing to sort.

The only exception is if I sort with `ORDER BY rowid` (instead of `ORDER BY col2`), or when I do it like this (0.5 seconds):

```
SELECT * FROM "mytable" WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid FROM "mytable"  WHERE col1="foo") ORDER BY col2
```

I `VACUUM`'ed the DB and I checked the integrity of the DB (ok) and this problem persists.
I am using SQLite version: 3.7.7.1, the slowdowns appear both in phpLITEadmin and in my PHP code.

**Edit**

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM "mytable" WHERE col1="foo"
```

```
selectid|order|from|detail
       0|    0|   0|SCAN TABLE mytable (~11345 rows)
```

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM "mytable" WHERE col1="foo" ORDER BY col2
```

```
selectid|order|from|detail
       0|    0|   0|SEARCH TABLE mytable USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (col1=?) (~7 rows)
       0|    0|   0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

Comment: Do you know what an index is?

Comment: create an index on col2, this will avoid creating a temp btree

Comment: @Peeyush There is already an index on col2. I ran tests with and without index on col2, the result is the same = 120 seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it seems SQLite erroneously thinks it would be cheaper to build a temporary index ([automatic covering index](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx)) to run your query instead of sorting in memory. Obviously building an index on 100,000 rows for every query isn't the most optimal query plan.

An obvious solution would be to add an index on the columns on which you want to perform querying/sorting.

```
CREATE INDEX col1_idx ON mytable (col1);
CREATE INDEX col2_idx ON mytable (col2);
```

Comment: That index already exists and makes no difference. Both with and without index it takes 120 seconds.

Comment: @Mike.M also on `col1`?

Comment: No, col1 did not have any index and creating an index seems to have solved this problem, or I should say, circumvented this SQLITE bug. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

We ran into a similar issue and adding a dummy computed value and using it for sorting resolved this 'bug':

```
SELECT *, (col2+0) AS col2_forSort FROM "mytable" where col1="foo" ORDER BY col2_forSort
```

or for string (which was not our case):

```
SELECT *, (col2 || "") AS col2_forSort FROM "mytable" where col1="foo" ORDER BY col2_forSort
```

YMMV...Good luck!

Comment: What is your SQLite version?

Comment: @Mike.M Vesion `3.22.0` on an embedded device.